# Get a list of directory names and output to file

Tags: c#, filesystems, io, directory-structure

I am looking for the best method for a windows computer to grab a directory listing, output the result to a formatted text file I can then use to make a SQL update.

Directories are formated:

```
/<Category-Name>/img.jpg
```

or

```
/<Category-Name>/images/*.jpg
/<Category-Name>/thumbnails/*.jpg
```

or

```
/<Category-Name>/full/*.jpg
/<Category-Name>/thumb/*.jpg
```

What I was considering is a output file containing:

```
<Category-Name>,f,blah1.jpg
<Category-Name>,f,blah2.jpg
<Category-Name>,t,blah3.jpg
etc...
```

My limitations are that I am not on, nor do I have access to a Linux computer for nifty tools such as `cat`. So I have decided C# and the .Net framework are my best bet to accomplish this. I believe Python or Perl would do just as well but I have yet to learn either language.

Any suggestions on how to write such a program or other ideas on how to tackle this are most welcome.

To be clear, my intentions are to get a directory listing with files all ending in '.jpg' outputted to a text file in a way that I can manipulate to create an SQL INSERT into a database. Programming something to accomplish this would take considerably less time than making each entry through a Content Management system for this and future tasks. The directories are easily in the thousands.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DirectoryInfo should give you what you need -- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directoryinfo.aspx

Comment: Beautiful work, got the listing of files with extension *.jpg to an array complete with file path. Now to write that to a comma seperated file which i can work with.

Answer (score 1):

You could use Linq-to-FileSystem to query a directory, listing all the folders, files and sub-folders. The article below demonstrates the API:

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/linq/LinqToTree.aspx#filesystem

Comment: After some reading I think .net has what I need to read directories and files built-in. My current issue now is figuring out how best to write and append the results to a file. And how exactly I plan to read that file with SQL to make an Insert. For something so simple in Linux and MySQL this is proving to be such a pain. Can't stand Windows, but it is a necessary evil for my current job. So back to figuring out C# and MSSql.